# How to adjust table in Quarto from being out of page?

Tags: r-markdown, quarto

I am using Quarto to create a document where I have code chunks and a table both are running beyond the page margin.
This is my YAML:

```
---
title: "SSA"
format: pdf
pdf_document:
    papersize: "letter"
    margin: "1in"
editor: visual
---
```

And this is a code chunk and the code for a table.

```
# Load data

data <- read_excel("C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/PLA/Course Materials/Week 7/ShiftShare.xlsx")


data %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  kable(
    caption = "Employment by Industry: United States and New York (2012 and 2022)",
    align = c("l", rep("c", 4)),  # Specify alignment for each column
    col.names = c("Industry Codes", "2012", "2022", "2012", "2022"),  # Rename the second-order headings
    format.args = list(big.mark = ",")
  ) %>%
  kable_classic() %>%
  add_header_above(
    header = c(" " = 1, "United States" = 2, "New York" = 2),
    align = "c"
  )
```

When rendered as PDF, both part of the code chunk and the table are not showing up. Below is the example:
[image]

I have three more columns to the right in the table. As you can see, I tried adjusting the table width, but to no avail.
I understand that the first colum has too long texts and I would not mind wrapping those in several lines, if that helps bringing the table to show up correctly. I do not want to render it as HTML.

How to, then, do it for both the code chunk and the table?